# Populate single field in one database from other two databases using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have three database in mongodb named ContactUser, SocialUser and AllUsers. Users who signup with contact number are added in ContactUser and user who do with social (fb, google) are added in SocialUser. Both db have users with their respected ids that are stored in AllUsers. Now I want to get list of all the users (UNION JOIN OF SOCIALUSER AND CONTACTUSER). How can I acheive that?

I tried using populate but it only shows data from one database. I want to get users from both the database. Right now, I am using this.

```
     const allUsersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
          userId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "SocialUser"
            required: true,
          }
    })


const users = await AllUsers.find({})
    .populate("userId");
```

Comment: It might be easier to have `contact: {..., ref: 'ContactUser'}` and `social: {..., ref: 'SocialUser'}` in allUsersSchema and populate both

Comment: Its not needed. The userId field is created from taking data from both databases. Using this method makes it more complicated then required. Plus AllUsers already consist of field named "LoginType" to check if user is social/contact logged in.